# Android colour resource - making a colour an alias of another

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
<color name="gray1">#eeeeee</color>
<color name="separator_line_gray">@color/gray1</color>
```

So that I can use `separator_line_gray` in my code and quickly change it from gray1 to gray2 if needed

Comment: that's correct. What's the issue?

Comment: yes you can  change that without any problem..

Comment: Not trying to sound rude but you could have quite easily tried this out before posting the question :)

Answer (score 4):

Your code is ok. You can do it like that, but you can also define a style that you always use and changes (e.g. color) you make to your style are applied to all the widgets that are using the style. Pretty cool huh?